# Does Triton trigger the active atmosphere of Neptune?

Tags: neptune, triton

As we know the atmosphere of Neptune looks more active than Uranus', is this due to the tidal forces caused by the retrograde orbit of Triton around the planet?

Comment: Unlikely.   Neptune is warmer than Uranus, more internal heat means more turbulent atmosphere.  The reason why this is so isn't known, but it's possible that Uranus had a more turbulent past and it emitted heat from it's formation more quickly.   It's also possible that Neptune had a collision more recently that may have added to it's internal heat.   Triton is too small to have the effect you describe and the retrograde motion isn't a factor.   http://www.spaceanswers.com/solar-system/why-is-uranus-colder-than-neptune/   (putting as a comment due to brevity)

Answer (score 1):

*Converting answer in comment to community wiki*

Unlikely. Neptune is warmer than Uranus, more internal heat means more turbulent atmosphere. The reason why this is so isn't known, but it's possible that Uranus had a more turbulent past and it emitted heat from its formation more quickly. It's also possible that Neptune had a collision more recently that may have added to its internal heat. Triton is too small to have the effect you describe and the retrograde motion isn't a factor.